# Nested associative array from DB fetch

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, mysqli

i want to do the following but haven't found how to.

Or i'm not sure if there is a better way / practice, if you can point me that way i will appreciate it.

I have 2 tables on my DB

- Table1 : Categories
- Table2 : Subcategories

**Table2** is associated with **table1** by the primary key.

So for 1 row in the **table1** i can have multiple associated rows on the **table2**.

I query and fetch the data on my **Table1** like this:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1");

$post = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $row->sub = get_subcategories($row['id']); /* this value is added to the array since i want to store in here the associated arrays from the table2 */
        $post[] = $row;
    }
return $post;
```

Then i do the following query also on another function for the table2 data based on every id from the table1

```
function get_subcategories($id){
   $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table2 where categories_id = '$id'");

   $post = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()){
        $post[] = $row;
    }
return $post;
}
```

But the result im getting when using var_dump doesn't seem right.

Can i do it? or what am i doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the result from the var_dump?

Comment: Why don't you use one query using JOIN.

Comment: You're assigning the array to `$post`, but returning `$posts` (with an extra `s`).

Comment: `$row['sub']` won't work when you use `fetch_object`, it should be `$row->sub`.

Comment: @barmar didn't noticed, just fixed it, mixed a code when i pasted it. thanks

Comment: What am i doing wrong in my question that i got downvoted? i think that asking for clarification or better practice is the way to go here on stackoverflow, also comment why are you downvoting an OP's question in order to help him avoid further mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a single JOIN query:

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.categories_id = t1.id ORDER BY t1.id"); 
$posts = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_object) {
    if (!isset($posts[$row->categories_id])) {
        $posts[$row->categories_id] = $row;
        $posts[$row->categories_id]->sub = array();
    }
    $posts[$row->categories_id]->sub[] = $row;
}
```

This will create nested arrays. The first level will be an associative array whose keys are category IDs and values are objects. The objects will have a `sub` property that is an array of all the subcategories. Both the categories and subcategories are the objects returned by `fetch_object`, so there will be duplication. But you can just refer to the appropriate object properties for a particular level.

Comment: Try it and use `var_dump()` to see.

Comment: Ok i tried and it seems to be working, or at least it's bringing the proper ammount of rows on table2 but i'm getting the same result for every item like this

**Electronica
Celulares
Celulares
Celulares
Celulares
Celulares**

Maybe i'm doing something wrong on the loop, but almost there. :)

Comment: All the elements of a particular `sub` array will be the same except for the properties specific to subcategories.